# Postgres mount volume error in k8s

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy Postgres with a `PersistentVolumeClaim` in GKE. As per the [description here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (look at `PGDATA`), it is recommended to create a subdirectory if mounting an external volume. So, this is what I did with my PG deployment:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: postgres-dev
      image: "postgres:12.1"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
      env:
        - name: PGDATA
          value: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-persistent-storage-dev
          mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
  volumes:
    - name: postgres-persistent-storage-dev
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: postgres-pvc-dev
```

I create the `/pgdata` subdir in `/postgresql/data`, which would be the original mount point for Postgres' data.

But when I try to deploy the Postgres pod, it stalls at Back-off error, and I get the following events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age               From                                                  Message
  ----     ------                  ----              ----                                                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled               20s               default-scheduler                                     Successfully assigned default/postgres-dev-7f549754d-nm2lf to gke-cluster-pool-1-4ce1e4d6-m33c
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  15s               attachdetach-controller                               AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-eea8ee4d-9d00-11ea-a854-42010a8a0057"
  Normal   Pulled                  9s (x2 over 10s)  kubelet, gke-cluster-pool-1-4ce1e4d6-m33c             Container image "postgres:12.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                 9s (x2 over 10s)  kubelet, gke-cluster-pool-1-4ce1e4d6-m33c             Created container postgres-dev
  Normal   Started                 9s (x2 over 10s)  kubelet, gke-cluster-pool-1-4ce1e4d6-m33c             Started container postgres-dev
  Warning  BackOff                 7s (x2 over 8s)   kubelet, gke-cluster-pool-1-4ce1e4d6-m33c             Back-off restarting failed container
```

These are the logs from the Postgres container:

```
initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" exists but is not empty
It contains a lost+found directory, perhaps due to it being a mount point.
Using a mount point directly as the data directory is not recommended.
Create a subdirectory under the mount point.
```

So, I create the subdir for mountpoint, as recommented for `initdb`, and then it complains about it. The PVC was created just right before the deployment, so there is no data in it.

I tried with completely new, un-existent dir like `/var/lib/postgres/data` as well, but the effect is the same.

Another interesting point is that when I set this up in `minikube`, everything works fine.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 7):

After some more careful reading of the Postgres error log, I realized that the problem is that I *set the mount point path and the data path to be the same dir*. This specific part of the log message in the Postgres container is the crucial one:

```
Using a mount point directly as the data directory is not recommended.
Create a subdirectory under the mount point.
```

I changed the value of `PGDATA` env var to be `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` (which is the DB data dir) and the mount point to be `/var/lib/postgresql/data` (which is the dir that Postgres initializes itself from).

After this change, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the PGDATA field that maybe the cause of the issue. I faced the same error, this comes because there's as LOST+FOUND folder already in that directory however, the container wants it to be a empty dir. Giving the subPath field solves this issue. Please try this it should solve the issue and you need not need any PGDATA field. Add **subPath** to some folder. Please go through following manifests.

https://github.com/mendix/kubernetes-howto/blob/master/postgres-deployment.yaml

https://www.bmc.com/blogs/kubernetes-postgresql/

it's a statefulset that usually you should go with and not a deployment when it comes to Database deployment.

```
        - name: postgredb
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
         #setting subPath will fix your issue it can be pgdata or 
         #postgres or any other folder name according to your 
         #choice.
          subPath: postgres
```